# CXF: How to intercept SOAP response

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I need to catch response from SOAP webservice I'm calling.
I've implemented interceptor as described [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html) to catch the incoming message:

```
client.getInInterceptors().add(new MyInterceptor());
```

the class is like the following:

```
public class MyInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<SoapMessage> {
    public MyInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.POST_LOGICAL_ENDING);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(final SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
          // Do stuff
    }
}
```

It is on POST_LOGICAL_ENDING phase, but the issue is that handleMessage () is not being called.
We have similar interceptor on outgoing message catching PRE_PROTOCOL_ENDING which works perfectly fine with the service.

What did I miss?
Should I use different phase?

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have to add this interceptor to the out* -> getOutInterceptors()

Comment: You know, or you guess?